# Loading JQuery when clicking on default search

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a requirement where if I click on sharepoint default search, so before searching I need to run a JQuery code which would append some parameter to the search.

Please suggest how this  can be done.

Comment: You can start your investigation on Search Box display templates.

Answer (score 0):

- Add (standard SP technology since SP2010) UserCustomActions to the Site Collection

  - https://github.com/tavikukko/Chrome-SP-Editor
  - or https://spusercustomactionmanageronline.codeplex.com/
- Load jQuery
- Load your script that always attaches to the search-box